# Duplicate & identify certain rows in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, duplicates, rows

I want to identify & duplicate with regex certains rows of my DataFrame.

For example my df :

```
   var1  
0  House A and B 
1  2 garage + garden 
2  fridges
```

The result that i want in var2 (keep my var1 too) :

```
   var1                  var2
0  House A and B         House A
1  House A and B         House B
2  2 garage + garden     Garage 1
3  2 garage + garden     Garage 2
4  2 garage + garden     Garden
5  fridges               fridge 1
6  fridges               fridge 2
```

I don't know exactly how to do that, I think with regex it's a good idea, but i'm not sur.

Thank for your help.

Comment: Each row uses a different rule to determine what to do in variable 2, so you'll have to be very careful with the different cases you'll have to write code for.

Comment: Yes, sure. It’s just a sample of my data frame

Comment: Someone can help me ? Please

Comment: The problem is your question is very broad and probably the sample isn't enough to generalize to your whole data set. I'll help you with the first example, but still, it won't necessarily work if there can be more than two items.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is very broad, so here's a little help with your first case scenario:

```
import re
import pandas as pd

var1 = pd.DataFrame(['House A and B'], columns=['var1'])

new_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['var1','var2'])
for idx,string in enumerate(var1):

    if re.search(r'\band\b',var1.iloc[idx][0]):

        df_aux = pd.DataFrame(var1.iloc[idx].repeat(2).reset_index(drop=True))
        df_aux.columns=['var1']
        new_df = new_df.append(df_aux, sort=True)
        last_letter = re.search(r'and.(\w+).*', var1.iloc[idx][0]).group(1)
        first_letter =re.search(r'(\w+).and.*', var1.iloc[idx][0]).group(1)
        trimmed_string = re.search(r'(\w+) .*', var1.iloc[idx][0]).group(1)
        new_df.var2.iloc[-2] = trimmed_string + ' ' + first_letter 
        new_df.var2.iloc[-1] = trimmed_string + ' ' + last_letter
```

Output:

```
            var1     var2
0  House A and B  House A
1  House A and B  House B
```

This will be very inefficient on big datasets because of two reasons: `regex` are slow and you should try to avoid looping through a DataFrame as much as possible. But because your sample is probably quite incomplete, this at least should be robust. You can use this same logic to extract the info you're looking for from the other patterns.